# Modern treatment of Delange's Tauberian Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, dirichlet-series, laplace-transform, tauberian-theorems

Tauberian theorems abound in the literature. One of the most general, powerful, and versatile is due to Delange, and appears as Theorem I of the paper:

H. Delange -  Généralisation du théorème de Ikehara, Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure, Série 3, Tome 71 (1954) no. 3, pp. 213-242.

Now this result was published in the 1950's and my understanding is that it was very influential. But this was a long time ago. Is there a modern treatment of Delange's result anywhere in the literature? For example whether the proof or some of his long list of technical assumptions have been simplified with hindsight. Or maybe it has been generalised?

I'm ultimately interested in applying this result  to a Dirichlet series to deduce an asymptotic formula for the partial sums of the coefficients. Delange's result is stated in terms of Laplace transforms, but there is a standard trick to apply this to Dirichlet series.

Please note that I am *not* looking for results with significantly stronger assumptions; in particular I do not want to assume that my Dirichlet series admits a holomorphic extension to some line, only that it admits a continuous extension to the line. For me this is part of the power of Delange's result, as is also the case for the Wiener-Ikehara Tauberian theorem.

Comment: A quick search gives me this https://rikkyo.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=repository_uri&item_id=8669&file_id=18&file_no=1

Comment: Yes I had already come across this paper, but Theorem 1 is significantly weaker than Delange's result. It only allows singularities of the type $1/(s-a)^\alpha$, whereas Delange's result covers more general singularities (e.g. those of the shape $1/(s-a)^{3/2} + 1/(s-a)^{1/2})$.

Comment: It seems that the only slight generalization following Kable's argument is the paper of [Kato](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.0427.pdf), Theorem 2.1, which consider additional  $\dfrac{1}{(s−a)^{\alpha_{i}}}$ with $\alpha_{i}<\alpha$, respect to Theorem 1 in Kable's paper, but probably you've also checked it, so it's just in case

Comment: The result of Kato is closer to what I'm after. But Delange's result is more general still, as for example, Delange also allows logarithmic singularities. I was more hoping for something like a textbook which treats Delange's result, or a research paper which generalises it.

Comment: Have you checked the textbook "Tauberian Theory: A Century of Developments" by Jacob Korevaar?

Comment: @Peter: Yes I have. I was surprised given that this is such a long and detailed book, Delange's result is only briefly mentioned in passing in a remark. If anyone who is more familiar with this book knows a good place to look in it, I would be very happy.

Comment: hi Dan, did you ever find a reference to this theorem? (i find myself wanting a "textbook version" of it too)

Comment: @tomos: I'm afraid not. I think someone really needs to do this. I'm not sure I'm that person.